# Display "red-x"-like icon in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We are developing a plugin to provide suggestions to developers in their code and we want to highlight it with the help of an icon (similar to the red-x error icon in the image below). What is best to achieve it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a resource `marker` which you create with something like:

```java
IMarker marker = resource.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);

marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
// TODO more attributes
```

where `resource` is the `IFile` (or `IResource`).